# ASP.NET <%# Eval("Statement") %> Removes HTML String in Statement?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, azure-table-storage

I'm trying to dynamically populate a table in my ASP.NET webpage from an Azure Storage Table and one of the features I wanted to include is to change the color of the text depending on the value of the element.

I'm using a `DataList` object which is calling a `GetEntries()` method to get a list of all the objects to display.

The text in each cell of the table is dynamically displayed using:

```
<%# Eval("VariableName") %>
```

So I tried changing the color of the text by doing something like this for each object in the `GetEntries()` method:

```
if (condition) 
   VariableName = "<font color=\"red\">" + VariableName + "</font>";
else
   // ...
```

When I run my program, the text is still black and when I view source, the `<font color="red">Bob</font` is only `Bob`.

Does the HTML get stripped when using Eval?

If so, is there an efficient way to change the text color based on the values?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To render as *html* you can try this:

```
<asp:Literal Text='<%# Eval("VariableName") %>' Mode="PassThrough" runat="server" />
```

This requires that you have html (with color info) in `VariableName`, which may not be pretty.

**Alternative 1:**

But it will be better if you can add a public property say `VariableColor` (and leave `VariableName` unchanged):

```
public Color VariableColor
{
    get
    {
        return <condition>? Color.Red : Color.Empty;
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
<asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("VariableName") %>' ForeColor='<%# Eval("VariableColor") %>' runat="Server" />
```

**Alternative 2:**

Even better could be to create a public bool property (say `IsDangerous`) which evaluates the condition:

```
public bool IsDangerous
{
    get
    {
        return <condition>;
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
<asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("VariableName") %>' ForeColor='<%# ((bool)Eval("IsDangerous"))?Color.Red:Color.Empty %>' runat="Server" />
```

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that it always evaluates the false. Do you know why that is?

Comment: It's exactly what you put there and I set IsDangerous to true.

Comment: The _<condition> expression_ is supposed to be the criteria you want for your data-item to be colored. If you set that to true, it will always be _red_. If that is what you want, no need for all these. Just put `ForeColor = "Red"`. By the way, the public property is **not** the property of the _page-class_, it is of your _data-item-class_.

Comment: I know. I was just setting it to true to test it out. The problem is that regardless of whether `IsDangerous` is set to true or false, it's always evaluated to `false`.

Comment: Okay, I got it. I had to put extra parentheses around the Eval statement. `((Boolean)Eval("IsDangerous"))` =]

Comment: My test code had it; somehow got missed when I posted. Thanks. answer updated slightly.